# Custom Model Binder Not Validating Model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, data-annotations, custom-model-binder

I started to play around with knockout.js and in doing so I used the FromJsonAttribute (created by Steve Sanderson). I ran into an issue with the custom attribute not performing model validation. I put together a simple example-- I know it looks like a lot of code-- but the basic issue is how to force the validation of the model within a custom model binder.

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace BindingExamples.Models
{
    public class Widget
    {
        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and here is my controller:

```
using System;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using BindingExamples.Models;

namespace BindingExamples.Controllers
{
    public class WidgetController : Controller
    {

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(Widget w)
        {
            if(this.ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                TempData["message"] = String.Format("Thanks for inserting {0}", w.Name);
                return RedirectToAction("Confirmation");
            }
            return View(w);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult PostJson([koListEditor.FromJson] Widget w)
        {
            //the ModelState.IsValid even though the widget has an empty Name
            if (this.ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                TempData["message"] = String.Format("Thanks for inserting {0}", w.Name);
                return RedirectToAction("Confirmation");
            }
            return View(w);
        }

        public ActionResult Confirmation()
        {
            return View();
        }

    }
}
```

**My issue is that the model is always valid in my PostJson method.** For completeness here is the Sanderson code for the FromJson attribute:

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

namespace koListEditor
{
    public class FromJsonAttribute : CustomModelBinderAttribute
    {
        private readonly static JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();

        public override IModelBinder GetBinder()
        {
            return new JsonModelBinder();
        }

        private class JsonModelBinder : IModelBinder
        {
            public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
            {
                var stringified = controllerContext.HttpContext.Request[bindingContext.ModelName];
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(stringified))
                    return null;
                var model = serializer.Deserialize(stringified, bindingContext.ModelType);
                return model;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

#### Description

The `FromJsonAttribute` only binds to the model and does, like you said, no validation.

You can add validation to the `FromJsonAttribute` in order to validate the model's against his DataAnnotations attributes.

This can be done using the `TypeDescriptor` class.

> **TypeDescriptor** Provides information about the characteristics for a component, such as its attributes, properties, and events.

Check out my solution. I have tested it.

#### Solution

```
private class JsonModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        var stringified = controllerContext.HttpContext.Request[bindingContext.ModelName];
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(stringified))
            return null;
        var model = serializer.Deserialize(stringified, bindingContext.ModelType);

        // DataAnnotation Validation
        var validationResult = from prop in TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(model).Cast<PropertyDescriptor>()
                                from attribute in prop.Attributes.OfType<ValidationAttribute>()
                                where !attribute.IsValid(prop.GetValue(model))
                                select new { Propertie = prop.Name, ErrorMessage = attribute.FormatErrorMessage(string.Empty) };

        // Add the ValidationResult's to the ModelState
        foreach (var validationResultItem in validationResult)
            bindingContext.ModelState.AddModelError(validationResultItem.Propertie, validationResultItem.ErrorMessage);

        return model;
    }
}
```

#### More Information

- [TypeDescriptor Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.typedescriptor.aspx)
- [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations Namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, thank you, dknaack!! Your answer was exactly what I was looking for, except I want to validate after each property is bound b/c I have properties that are dependent on other properties, and I don't want to continue binding if a dependent property is invalid.

Here's my new BindProperty overload:

```
protected override void BindProperty(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, PropertyDescriptor propertyDescriptor){

    // if this is a simple property, bind it and return
    if(_simplePropertyKeys.ContainsKey(propertyDescriptor.Name)){
        this.BindSimpleProperty(bindingContext, propertyDescriptor);

    // if this is complex property, only bind it if we don't have an error already
    } else if (bindingContext.ModelState.IsValid){
        this.BindComplexProperty(bindingContext, propertyDescriptor);
    }

    // add errors from the data annotations
    propertyDescriptor.Attributes.OfType<ValidationAttribute>()
        .Where(a => a.IsValid(propertyDescriptor.GetValue(bindingContext.Model)) == false)
        .ForEach(r => bindingContext.ModelState.AddModelError(propertyDescriptor.Name, r.ErrorMessage));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I'm only starting to learn ASP.NET so don't take my solution seriously. I found [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/806415/Model-Binding-using-IModelBinder-and-DefaultModelB) and as you, tried to do a custom model binder. There was no validation. Then i just replaced IModelBinder interface with DefaultModelBinder and voula, it works. Hope I could help someone